# Unknown Disk Space, can't touch it

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-space

My visible Disk Usage minus free space is out by 123GB.

Clarification: Externally booted disk repair show no errors. Permissions have been fixed. Time Machine has had local off with: 
   sudo tmutil disablelocal

UPDATE: Free space seems to be rapidly jumping around. 40GB then 10, then 5 then 30GB, minute to minute. Directory listings are consistent, only the hidden space varies to correlate with the free space. DriveDX shows drive is healthy. Note in DaisyDisk reads: "Unfortunately Daisy Disk is unable to locate these data. They are not available to users." as per attached image. In the time it's taken me to write this revision, free space started at 5GB, jump to 40, and is presently 18GB.

Using

```
root# du -x -sk /*
```

The results add up to about 325GB of my 500GB SSD, yet OS shows only ~40GB available.

Disk Inventory X show this missing space as: "Space occupied by other files and folders" 123.1GB) and reports it separately from the free space...

At one point I moved a 60GB folder off the system (to get running again) and after a restart only had 30GB free.

I can't even tell if it's swap space (though that should be in /private/var/vm) or Time Machine snapshots (but they're supposed to be in /.MobileBackups)

Daisy Disk reports the space as hidden, that's not helping me so far.

OS X 10.10.3, SSD 500.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What does  > About This Mac > Storage say about your HD space?

Comment: I would use OmniDiskSweeper

Comment: About This Mac's storage reports 360GB in "Other", the rest of the categories look correct, including free space of about ~40GB.

Comment: I provided an image of OmniDiskSweeper though I did not refer to it in my text: it neglects to report on this hidden/missing space nor does it report on free space.

Comment: The header at the top linking the answer elsewhere is not the answer in my case, though it got me digging into the DU command. Using "DU -h -d 1 ." shows that SPOTLIGHT is the CULPRIT and that OmniDiskSweeper is wring in that directory (permissions probably).